# TypeScript: ev.target and Node.contains: EventTarget is not assignable to Node

Tags: html, typescript

Here's the code:

```
function bodyClickHandler(ev: MouseEvent) {
    if(containerRef.current && containerRef.current.contains(ev.target)) return;
    setOpen(false);
}
```

The error:

[image]

> Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node | null'.
>     Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 44 more.ts(2345)

`containerRef.current` is a `HTMLDivElement`. `.contains` ought to be [this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

Is `ev.target` not guaranteed to be a `Node` of some sort?

I can cast it (`ev.target as Node`) but I'm trying to figure out in what scenario this could possibly fail? What can I click on that isn't a Node?

Comment: Though they probably don't all make sense in case of mouse events, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts lists 55 interfaces besides `Node` that extend `EventTarget`.

Comment: @Oblosys Hmm.. seems like a deficiency in lib.dom.ts; I think MouseEvent should be more specific :-( Oh well.

Comment: I think it's tricky to come up with accurate typings for `EventType` with TypeScript's type system. For `currentTarget` it's easier, but looking at your code example it seems you indeed need `target`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Short answer: It's due to poor typings on their part. Go ahead and cast it.

Long answer: The reason this happens is because if you click on an `<svg />` inside a button (for example), the `event.target` will point to the SVG, which is not guaranteed to be a button (obviously). Only an event's `currentTarget` points to the element the handler's on. Therefore the people who made the React typings decided that they would define and event's `currentTarget` as what the `button` was in our example, but make *no guarantees* about the event's `target` except that it is an EventTarget. Therefore you are stuck with having to cast it. This is discussed in [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239).

Comment: This isn't the synthetic `MouseEvent` though. I am using React, but React doesn't provide easy access to add events to `document.body`, so this is a native one added via `document.body.addEventListener`.

Comment: @mpen It looks like they have the same feature/problem in the DOM typings. If anything, it's worse because DOM `MouseEvent`s aren't generic.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be `button` but it is at least guaranteed to be a `Node`, right?

Comment: I would think so.

Answer (score 14):

I'm just starting with Typescript. I have a similar problem, my solution is, I know that the event is always fired by a DomElement.

And this is how I inform Typescript:

```
function bodyClickHandler(ev: MouseEvent) {
    if(containerRef.current && containerRef.current.contains(ev.target as HTMLElement)) return;
    setOpen(false);
}
```

If you prefer to separate it:

```
function bodyClickHandler(ev: MouseEvent) {
    const target = ev.target as HTMLElement;
    if(containerRef.current && containerRef.current.contains(target)) return;
    setOpen(false);
}
```